# How should I define a __repr__ for a class hierarchy in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, slots, repr

Given the following code:

```
class Base:

    __slots__ = 'base_field',

    def __init__(self, base_field):
        self.base_field = base_field

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__}(base_field={self.base_field!r})"

class Derived(Base):

    __slots__ = 'derived_field',

    def __init__(self, derived_field, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.derived_field = derived_field

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{self.__class__.__name__}(base_field={self.base_field!r}, derived_field={self.derived_field!r})"


b1 = Base('base')
print(repr(b1))
b2 = eval(repr(b1))

d1 = Derived(base_field='dbase', derived_field='derived')
print(repr(d1))
d2 = eval(repr(d1))
```

This code will break if I add a new field to `Base` and forget to update the `Derived` class' `__repr__`.

How and where should I define a `__repr__` method(s) such that:

- When I pass both `Base` and `Derived` instances to `repr()`, their correct strings will be returned (e.g. `repr(Base("base")) == "Base(base_field="base")` and `repr(Derived(base_field='dbase', derived_field='derived')) == "Derived(base_field="base", derived_field="derived")`
- I can safely add fields to the `Base` class and those fields will show up in in the `Derived` class' `__repr__` output.  In other words, the `Derived` class' `__repr__` function should not know about the fields in the `Base` class.
- The code is minimal.  If I have to add more than a couple of lines, the extra code might not be worth it

I'm reading some code where the author has solved the problem by making the `Derived` class `__repr__` call `super().__repr__()` and then remove the last parenthesis and append the `Derived` attributes to the string.  This does the job but I'm wondering if there is a more Pythonic way of achieving this goal.  Or, perhaps this is the Pythonic way?

I looked into Python's `dataclass` and that does a great job of building `__repr__`s that do the right thing.  However they use `__dict__`s so there are trade-offs to consider (e.g. smaller memory foot print for an object that has many instances at once, vs. easier `__repr__`).

Thank you!

Comment: I'm on mobile so I can't check but you can take a look at `self.__dict__`

Comment: If you are trying to serialize and deserialize your instances, don't use a combination of `repr` and `eval`. Write explicit (de)serialization functions.

Comment: @chepner Thanks for the advice.  We're not using this code for serialization purposes.

Comment: @Asocia thanks for the lead.  Unfortunately we're using __slots__ so the classes have no __dict__.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this dynamically, just introspect on slots and make sure to walk the MRO:

```
class Base:

    __slots__ = 'base_field',

    def __init__(self, base_field):
        self.base_field = base_field

    def __repr__(self):
        slots = [
            slot
            for klass in type(self).mro() if hasattr(klass, '__slots__')
            for slot in klass.__slots__
        ]
        args = ", ".join(
            [f"{slot}={getattr(self, slot)!r}" for slot in reversed(slots)]
        )
        return f"{type(self).__name__}({args})"

class Derived(Base):

    __slots__ = 'derived_field',

    def __init__(self, derived_field, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.derived_field = derived_field
```

You can just put this in a function, and re-use the code in various hierarchies.

```
    def slotted_repr(obj):
        slots = [
            slot
            for klass in type(obj).mro() if hasattr(klass, '__slots__')
            for slot in klass.__slots__
        ]
        args = ", ".join(
            [f"{slot}={getattr(obj, slot)!r}" for slot in reversed(slots)]
        )
        return f"{type(obj).__name__}({args})"
```

Comment: I can't decide if that's more evil or genius, but I love it.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I explored the `mro` approach and it did everything I wanted but I held out hope that there was a more pythonic way I didn't know about.  I really like the idea of factoring it into a function.  Combine that with a function named dict_repr and that would be very helpful.  Thanks!!

Comment: For posterity, the `hasattr()` check is important because object, the last class in the MRO, does not have `__slots__`.